# ORM / Doctrine set multiple filters for ArrayCollections

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I filter an ArrayCollection in this way:

```
$result = $eCollection->getElements()->filter(
   function($rObject) use ($id) {
      return in_array($rObject->getEid(), array($id));
   }
);
```

But the collection has also an attribute called type and one called date.

How can I filter it by ID and TYPE, or by DATE between to values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`. You can read all about criteria in chapter **[8.8. Filtering Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)** in the doctrine 2 documentation.
The advantage of using criteria is that you can add all kinds of constraints and it will be performed on database level. This means you won't unnecessary load any elements in your collection that you do not want to have.

```
$elements = $eCollection->getElements();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("id", $id))
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq("type", $type))
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->between('date', $from, $to));

$result = $elements->matching($criteria);
```